# The Electronics Involved in Instruction Fetching

Tags: voltage, electromagnetism, control, cpu

I would like to know how the [instruction cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle) works at an electronics level. I am new to electronics.

In order to limit the scope of this question, I am just focusing on the first step of the cycle, "instruction fetch". I understand the high-level descriptions like from Wikipedia (below), so here I am wondering the details of electronics involved.

Specifically, I am wondering like how many flip-flops, gates, buses, whatever else involved, and what is connected to what (at a high-level). I am new to electronics so I'm not too familiar with all the components involved, so don't really know how to explain the detail I am hoping for. I guess basically down to the voltage. If there are any transistors. If there are any magnets, optics, etc.

For example, "There are x number of flip-flops, each connected to a central data bus made out of s, which is connected to x. The electrons flow from y to the central data bus on a wire (typically made out of copper) to the flip flops, which is the initiation of the instruction fetch process. This then triggers w process in the t electrical component which induces a voltage change to cause a sequence of voltage changes to then send the resulting "information" (electrons sent in packets passing through the bus on the copper wires to the flip-flop [entry point] to be stored in a voltage difference) is sent back to the ..." As you can see I have no idea what I'm talking about, but that is sort of the idea of the level of detail I am looking for. The whole process doesn't need to be described, just looking for an introduction to the pieces involved. Trying to make the connection from the Wikipedia-level description down to the level of voltages, materials (silicon/magnets/etc.), and components (transistors, flip-flops).

Thank you so much for your help.

---

> [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cycle) The fetch step is the same for each instruction:
>
> 1. The CPU sends the contents of the PC to the MAR and sends a read command on the address bus
> 2. In response to the read command (with address equal to PC), the memory returns the data stored at the memory location indicated by PC on the data bus
> 3. The CPU copies the data from the data bus into its MDR (also known as MBR, see section Components above)
>      A fraction of a second later, the CPU copies the data from the MDR to the instruction register for instruction decoding
> 4. The PC is incremented so that it points to the next instruction. This step prepares the CPU for the next cycle.
> 5. The control unit fetches the instruction's address from the memory unit.

Comment: "Bebop Bytes Back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers" is what I'd recommend you read. Sadly, I cornered the market of the spare copies it seems (I bought up a dozen at about $15 each on Amazon and now I see they are about $100 each!!) I've been giving them away. (Maybe I should change my behavior.)

Comment: Computers are literally abstractions built on top of abstractions.  Or, to put it another way, complex things are built from simpler things.  So this top down question is going to be really hard to answer.  And really does not fit into the stacexchange one-well-defined-question & one-concise-answer paradigm.  All that said, in theory, you can build an entire computer out of a "universal gate".  A NAND gate (usually made of a half dozen transistors) is a good example.  From there you can build a latch.  From that memory. And so on...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to make a connection between software code and electrons, you need to start with basics of digital logic.

First, there are no "electrons" in digital design, electrons are abstracted to "voltage levels" on some wires, or "nodes" as they are called. More, the "voltage levels" are further reduced/abstracted to only two levels, "HIGH" and "LOW", which are separated by some threshold, so the levels that can be "registered" by "flip-flop" are only HIGH or LOW, representing logical "TRUE" (or "1"), and "FALSE (or "0"). And nothing in between. So all signals in a digital design are assuming "1" or "0" values, on every wire connection. From this point you should forget about "electrons" or "voltage differences".

Then you need to comprehend how the basic digital logic elements work.

There are combinatorial LOGIC elements that take two or more inputs, and output some simple result in accord with their TRUTH TABLE. How do they do it should not concern you at this level, electrons are abstracted out, and a bunch of carefully interconnected transistors do the job. These basic elements are NORs, NANDs, etc. And "decoders"/"encoders".

There are "memory elements" like flip-flops, which can "remember" the state of input logic value after a "clock" event, usually a transition of some logic signal from low to high, or from high to low. The input value is "latched" now. A group of certain number of FFs constitutes a "register". If the clock doesn't toggle, the FF will remember the logic state.

There are elements that can pass a data signal if enabled by some other signal, or block the signal propagation if disabled. These elements are called "mulitpexors" (or "MUXes"), or "bi-directional bus drivers". They are used to direct data flows (wire connections) between different "units" or "registers", to disconnect logic units from data busses and/or connect the bus to another destination or source of data.

Once you master an understanding of functionality of these basic elements, you can start thinking of how data can be stored in arrays of registers, how to address the individual registers (or "memory locations"), and get the stored data on a bus. Then "fetching" an instruction or operand would be to address the memory location by one set of wires, force the memory to output the data it contains, direct/enable the bus of data wires to desired destination (as input to decoder), and latch these data for decoding. This is done by a carefully-designed  sequencer, or "Control Unit" from your previous question.

When some explanatory text says "sends command", or "memory returns" something, it all means that some digital block enables distinct voltage levels on a bunch of wires, and another block (as memory cell/register) asserts its content on another bus (bunch of wires for data). A lingo "CPU copies" means that these instant data values were latched into a dedicated register (a separate bunch of FFs) in proper moment, and remain there while the data bus can be connected to another memory location or another source/operand. The electrons here are needed only to remember that signals propagate at finite speed, and there needs to be some time for the levels to settle to robust digital levels before latching the data up.

All this is written in hundreds of books, so I hope you are not mocking people here asking to explain the entire digital electronics in on page. But I tried.

Comment: Wow this is an excellent answer. Thank you so much! No I am not mocking lol. This was super helpful, I literally have no experience in electronics and it would take forever to grasp what you just outlined.

Comment: Excellent job with the basics. I understand at some point you just had to stop-or go on forever. +1

Comment: +1, I'm going to bookmark it for your second paragraph alone, and point people at it when this comes up again, as it will, again, and again!

Answer (score 1):

At one time, directed to automate some temperature testing and the recording of swept-frequency data gathered over those temperatures, and denied the use of MC6800 ICs, I designed some (very slow) state machines.

The memory was MonolithicMemories 256 words of 8 bits. If the MSB was a 1, this was a Jump to an EvenNumber new address for the Program Counter, that jump done simply by loading the 7LSBs into the 7 MSBs of the 8-bit Program Counter.

By double-pulsing the Program Counter, based on some condition codes (such as 90-second-thermal-settling-delay still-not-complete), we had Increment_and_Skip instructions, such as the DataGeneral Nova1200 minicomputers used.

The thermal-sequencing state-machine needed no math.

The data-logger did use an adder (4+4 bits, 8 bits wide) to convert from BCD codes into ASCII numeric codes.

How was all this done? by sitting, quietly, thinking thru the behaviors I needed to implement, and then using the 1974 TTL databook to provide pinout details of the ICs (almost all were 14/16 pins, except the MM PROM.

How was all this conceived? By reading the Signetics datasheets on their PROMS, to be used in microcoding, back in university days.

Comment: Frankly, this is still a good design as it is easy to verify that it is entirely functional correct.